# Heroku Error: Cannot find module './common'

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku

I was trying to deploy a practice project to Heroku and it gets deployed. However there is a application error, which is preventing the app to run on the server. I got some details about the errors, after running `heroku logs`.

```js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883329+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883379+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883379+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883379+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883380+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './common'
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883380+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883380+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883381+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/debug/src/index.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883381+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mquery/lib/mquery.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883382+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise_provider.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883382+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883382+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883382+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883383+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/internal.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883383+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883383+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883383+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883386+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/db/connect.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883386+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883388+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js:240:18)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883389+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883389+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883389+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883390+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883390+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883390+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883390+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/debug/src/node.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/debug/src/index.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mquery/lib/mquery.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883392+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise_provider.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883392+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/internal.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883393+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883394+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883394+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883394+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/db/connect.js',
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883394+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883394+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-03-07T01:25:09.883395+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-03-07T01:25:10.033008+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-07T01:25:10.264584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have installed the `common` package separately using `npm install common --save`, but that did not solve the issue. Also deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled all the modules. However nothing seems to work. I've scoured the internet for an answer to this, and haven't found anything yet that works.

My `package.json` looks like this,

```js
{
  "name": "starter-again",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "^0.2.5",
    "debug": "^4.3.3",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.0"
  },
}
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this error?

Comment: "I have installed the common package separately using npm install common --save, but that did not solve the issue"—that won't work on Heroku, and it's a bad idea anyway. Your dependencies should all be declared in your `package.json`. Please show us your `package.json` by [edit]ing it into your question. "Also deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled all the modules"—doing that locally shouldn't have any effect on Heroku. Is your `node_modules/` committed? (It shouldn't be.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
''Your dependencies should all be declared in your `package.json`'' — I had declared all the dependencies inside the `package.json` file [updated the question with `package.json`].  Secondly `node_modules/` is not committed, it is added in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: "Cannot find module './common'"—I'm not really a Node.js guy, but are you literally trying to import `./common`? Wouldn't you normally import `common`, without the `./`?

Comment: ''Are you literally trying to import ./common? '' — I haven't imported the module in my source code. I guess, some library function or internal package requires this `common` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by not having `node_modules` in my `.gitignore` folder which was there originally.